Django + spatialite migration IntegrityError
When I modify a class/table with PolygonField, the migration stops with the following error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'geometry_columns_statistics' with primary key 'new__mc_sitio_benfeitoria' has an invalid foreign key: geometry_columns_statistics.f_table_name contains a value 'new__mc_sitio_benfeitoria' that does not have a corresponding value in geometry_columns.f_table_name.

My app is MC_SITIO and the class follows:
class ImovelBase(ModelGis):
"""Base para Imóveis"""

descricao        = CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='descrição')
administrador    = ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
RIP              = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, help_text='se for imóvel da União')
codigo           = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='código, matricula, anúncio, ou outro documento')
endereco         = ForeignKey(Endereco, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'endereço')
poligono         = PolygonField(srid=EPSG_SRID_PADRAO, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='polígono')
# area_total       = UnumCharField(valid_unit=m**2, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='área total', validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0)])
area_total       = SympyCharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='área total')
VUP              = DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='valor unitário padrão (VUP)', max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0)])
indice_fiscal    = DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='índice fiscal', max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0)])
em_condominio    = BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='em condomínio')
observacoes      = TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='observações')

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def __str__(self):
    return "{0}".format(self.descricao)

def area(self):
    if self.poligono:
        return self.poligono.transform(get_SRID_UTM_WGS84(self.poligono.centroid), clone=True).area*m**2
    return "S/N"

@property
def popupConteudo(self):
    return '<a href="/terreno-{}.html" target="_blank">{}</a>'.format(self.id, self.descricao)

class TerrenoBase(ImovelBase):
"""Base para Terreno, tombo"""

relevo           = CharField(choices=RelevoClasse.choices, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='classe do relevo')
forma_regular    = BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='forma regular?')
esquinas_qtd     = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="quantidade de esquinas")
# testada          = UnumCharField(valid_unit=m, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
testada          = SympyCharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
testadas_qtd     = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="quantidade de testadas")
# gabarito         = UnumCharField(valid_unit=m, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
gabarito         = SympyCharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
macrozoneamento  = CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
zoneamento       = CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
tombamentos      = ManyToManyField(Referencia, blank=True, verbose_name='tombamento(s)')

class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Terreno(TerrenoBase):
"""Terreno, tombo"""

pass

class Benfeitoria(ImovelBase):
"""Benfeitoria, casa, prédio, galpão, ponte, edificação, ou qualquer outra construção permanente sobre um terreno"""

terreno       = ForeignKey(Terreno, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True)
tipob         = PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=BenfeitoriaTipo.choices, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='tipo da benfeitoria')
pav_desc      = CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='descrição dos pavimentos', help_text='T: térreo, PT: pav. tipo, LJ: loja, C: cobertura, etc')
rr_desc       = CharField(choices=RossHeidecke.choices, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Critério de Ross-Heidecke')
vida_util     = CharField(choices=BenfeitoriaVidaUtilPadrao.choices, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='vida útil padrão')

How to solve it?

The pertinent values (geometry_columns_statistics, new__mc_sitio_benfeitoria and geometry_columns.f_table_name) only appear in the message, not in the code. Add the pertinent code. Alternately the message tells you what the issue is. i.e. the row in question in table geometry_columns_statistics has a FKey conflict as the value being inserted/updated/left in the column(s) is not in the referenced columns(columns) of the geometry_columns.f_table_name table. In the case of left, it could be an attempt to delete the row from the geometry_columns.f_table_name table.

continuation. As it appears to be a migration you should ensure that the table(s) which are referenced by a Foreign Key constraint are loaded before the respective table that includes the Foreign Key constraint. So load the geometry_columns.f_table_name table before the geometry_columns_statistics table.
